# How can we buffer items in each milliseconds and stream each item at constant time interval

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java, rx-java2, rx-kotlin2

onNext method of publishSubject is calling continuously(in uneven time, approximately in 1 milliseconds)
And requirement is to emit these item at every 1 second and data should not loss means should emit each item.

```
    publishSubject.onNext("Data1");
    publishSubject.onNext("Data2");
    publishSubject.onNext("Data3");
    publishSubject.onNext("Data4");
    publishSubject.onNext("Data5");
    publishSubject.onNext("Data6");
    publishSubject.onNext("Data7");
```

and so on...
See Code Structure for Reference:

```
var publishSubject = PublishSubject.create<String>()
publishSubject.onNext(stateObject) // Executing at every milliseconds...


publishSubject
        /* Business Logic Required Here ?? */
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe {
            // Should execute at every 1 second
        }
```

Please help, Thanks in Advance,

Comment: Something like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33291245/rxjava-delay-for-each-item-of-list-emitted ?

Comment: What about storing the items in a Deque and use a coroutine that launches a suspending function to get the first element of the deque one a second ?

Comment: Your requirement is confusing. If data arrives once a millisecond and can be emitted only once a second, then after one second, you are 999 emissions behind and will never catch up. What do you want to do with them?

Comment: @BobDalgleish, yes now 999 emissions will emit at every second one by one

Comment: After 1 day, you will be about 86,313,600 items behind; after 12 days, you will be more than 1 million items behind. Do you not see a problem?

Comment: @BobDalgleish, Yes but it's not long time process like 12 days. it complete process of 10 to 15 minutes.

Comment: @BobDalgleish , It is something like buffering and streaming items.

Answer (score 1):

What about storing the items in a Deque. Then, use a coroutine that launches a suspending function to get the first element of the deque once every second ?

Here is some **quick and dirty** code just to make sure it works.
You can run this code online on the [kotlin website](https://pl.kotl.in/rybRIIuXE).
Please keep in mind that I'm very new to Kotlin.

```
val deque: Deque<String> = ArrayDeque()
var refMillisAdd: Long = 0
var refMillisTake: Long = 0

fun main() {

    println(" Delay(ms) -> Action")
    println("---------------------")

    kotlinx.coroutines.runBlocking {

        launch {

            refMillisAdd = currentTimeMillis()
            refMillisTake = currentTimeMillis()

            for(i in 0..20){
               oncePer10ms(i.toString())
               refMillisAdd = currentTimeMillis()
            }

            for(i in 0..6){
                oncePerSecond()
                refMillisTake = currentTimeMillis()
            }
        }
    }
}

suspend fun oncePerSecond(){
    kotlinx.coroutines.delay(1_000L)
    println("  ${currentTimeMillis() - refMillisTake} -> TAKE ${deque.pop()}")
}

suspend fun oncePer10ms(item: String){
    kotlinx.coroutines.delay(10L)
    deque.add(item)
    println("  ${currentTimeMillis() - refMillisAdd} -> ADD $item")
}
```

The code above prints:

```
 Delay(ms) -> Action
---------------------
  17 -> ADD 0
  11 -> ADD 1
  10 -> ADD 2
  10 -> ADD 3
  10 -> ADD 4
  10 -> ADD 5
  10 -> ADD 6
  10 -> ADD 7
  10 -> ADD 8
  11 -> ADD 9
  10 -> ADD 10
  10 -> ADD 11
  10 -> ADD 12
  11 -> ADD 13
  10 -> ADD 14
  10 -> ADD 15
  11 -> ADD 16
  10 -> ADD 17
  10 -> ADD 18
  10 -> ADD 19
  11 -> ADD 20
  1223 -> TAKE 0
  1000 -> TAKE 1
  1000 -> TAKE 2
  1001 -> TAKE 3
  1000 -> TAKE 4
  1000 -> TAKE 5
  1000 -> TAKE 6
```

Answer (score 1):

This function extension for `Observable` class is exactly what you need:

```
fun <T> Observable<T>.delayBetweenItems(timeout: Long, unit: TimeUnit): Observable<T> =
    Observable.zip(this, Observable.interval(timeout, unit), BiFunction<T, Long, T> { item, _ -> item })
```

You can declare it in some utility class in your project and then apply it just like other **RxJava** operators:

```
publishSubject
    .delayBetweenItems(1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribe {
        // Should execute at every 1 second
    }
```

Comment: It is working..but sometime(after a long time) it is getting disposed automatically. and no item is getting emit.

Comment: @RajatSharma I think the reason is in how you use it in Android rather than in a function itself. Try to check your code for subscribe and dispose logic.

Comment: it may be due we have not handled back press in it.