# Delay Element in RxJava Flowable

Tags: rx-java, project-reactor, rx-java3

There is a very intuitive operator named `delayElements` available in the @ProjectReactor publisher Flux to introduce a delay between each element emitted. Say, for example, following cod emit an element per second.

```
Flux.fromIterable(List.of(1, 2, 3))
      .delayElements(Duration.ofSeconds(1))
      .map(i -> i * 2)
      .doOnNext(r -> System.out.println(ZonedDateTime.now().toEpochSecond() + ": " + r))
      .blockLast();
```

To get the same behavior done in @Rxjava, I had to do some ceremony.

```
final List<Integer> data = List.of(1, 2, 3);    
Flowable.interval(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
      .take(data.size())
      .map(i -> data.get(i.intValue()) * 2)
      .doOnNext(r -> System.out.println(ZonedDateTime.now().toEpochSecond() + ": " + r))
      .blockingLast();
```

Does anyone know a better way to do the above in @Rxjava?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a rather simple approach [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41718758/2583726). Thanks, [Mina](https://stackoverflow.com/users/235123/mina-samy).

```
Flowable.just(1,2,3)
  .zipWith(Flowable.interval(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS), (item, interval) -> item)
  .subscribe(r -> System.out.println(r));
```